# The multipart identifier could not be bound in order/group by with joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[A] a
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[NM] nm ON a.ID = nm.PropertyId
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[PRO] pro ON pro.ID = nm.PropertyID_FK
WHERE a.Set = 'Pl_ch';
 -- GROUP BY a.NR // The multipart identifier could not be bound
 -- Order by a.NR // The multipart identifier could not be bound
```

Adding an Order by or Group by to the query above gets me the error:

> The multi-part identifier could not be bound for the a.NR field.

Why does it not work?

Comment: Why does it not work?  Because `NR` is not a column in `dbo.A`.

Comment: What is your requirement? Plus 'ORDER BY' should be used after WHERE condition.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The multi-part identifier could not be bound it means the Compiler is not able to find the column specified.**

`Order By` comes `after` `where` And If you use `group by` then you can **only select those columns which as present in group by** if you want to **select other columns you have to use aggregate function.**

```
SELECT a.[NR]
FROM [dbo].[A] a 
inner join [dbo].[NM] nm  on a.ID = nm.PropertyId 
inner join [dbo].[PRO] pro on pro.ID  = nm.PropertyID_FK
where  a.Set = 'Pl_ch'
GROUP BY a.[NR]
Order by a.[NR]
```

Comment: arg... I tried that before and it did not work because => I changed now the tablename.Set to a.Set and I did not realize I fixed another bug with that twist.

Comment: Check my answer now @Pascal

Answer (score 0):

> When it Say's *The multi-part identifier could not be bound* it means
>   the Compiler is not able to find the column specified.

So Here it is possible that you may not have a Column NR in Table A or Maybe there are possibilities that the Column Name may have spaces in it.

So Make sure the Column is spalled Correctly and Also if there are spaces in the Column Name, use Square Brackets to specify the Column name. Like `A.[NR ]` instead of `A.NR`

Answer (score -1):

Some ideas:

- Try a.[Set] instead of a.Set
- Try a.* instead of *
- Try selecting specific fields instead of using *

Comment: He is getting the Error For Column NR. So it has nothing to do with * or specifying the column names because the error says it is not able to find the Column NR in the table A